# Overridden (extended) Block function still called

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, extensions, overrides, phtml

I have made an extension for magento 2 (that filters the products shown depending on user). I have extended the file module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php for this and overwrittien the _getProductCollection() function. Whenever a user views products from the menu, the new _getProductCollection() function is called from the new Block file and the products are filtered. Perfect so far.

But whenever a user tries to view products by searching them (instead of using the menu) the products are not filtered. It turns out that when using search the old _getProductCollection() from the extended Block file module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php is called.

I find this very strange since it is the same .phtml file that is used in both cases (module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/produc/list.phtml).

So the problem is that both the new and the old (overwritten) block files are called from the same .phtml file. I have no clue how to proceed so any help is appreciated.